# Swift function with a function as parameter

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I have a question about why I get a compilation error of "Missing return in a function". I am following the examples in the "The Swift Programming Language" book and there is a section about passing a function as a parameter of another function.

Here is the book's example which compiles fine:

```
func hasAnyMatches(list: [Int], condition: Int -> Bool) -> Bool {
    for item in list {
        if condition (item) {// anonymous function call
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func lessThanTen(number: Int) -> Bool {
    return number < 10
}
```

I understand this, but I thought I could make a subtle change, because I felt the if condition(item){ } was redundant.
Here is my alteration:

```
func hasAnyMatches(list: [Int], condition: Int -> Bool) -> Bool {
    for item in list {
        return condition(item)
    }//error here with "Missing return in a function expected  to return bool"
}
```

I'm returning a bool because I return the result of the function. There is no case where I would not return a bool during the for-in loop.

I don't understand why this does not compile, could someone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your change doesn't do what the old code did. Your version returns the result of testing the first element in the list, not whether any of the elements pass the test.

The reason for the error is that your code isn't guaranteed to execute `return` at all. If the list is empty, then you'll drop to the end of the function without calling `return`. The compiler is telling you that.

Comment: I don't agree with your first sentence, but I understand the second.

Comment: Try running some tests where the first element returns false and the second element returns true. Compare the returned value of the original and your change. https://gist.github.com/rnapier/d4943113fbb6381172e8

Comment: Ah, I understand now. The return false at the end of the function is only executed if the entire list is >= 10 or if the list is empty. I was under the impression that the function returned false for every item in list less than 10. I thought the results were going to be true, true, false, false if given the list [8,9,10,11]

Comment: No; that would be `return list.map(condition)` and you would need to change the return type to `[Bool]` rather than `Bool`.

Answer (score 0):

```
func hasAnyMatches(list: [Int], condition: Int -> Bool) -> Bool {

for item in list {

         if condition(item) {
        return true
    }
}

return bool

}
```

Comment: I could return true or false at that line, but it would be unreachable code. Your answer doesn't really talk much about why that return statement is necessary though.